# How do I perform a collision check?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I have no clue what to do here, I want to make it so that a turtle in Python will shoot a bullet and if it collides with the other turtle, the score goes up. Except if I run this code, the game will crash when I shoot the bullet. So far, I only tried it for one of the eight move commands.

```
#imports turtles 
import turtle
import random
#Sets screen, turtle program, and colour group
turtle.setup(1000, 800)
screen = turtle.Screen()
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("springgreen")

amir = turtle.Turtle() 
amir.shape("arrow")
amir.shapesize(1)
amir.speed(10)
amir.pensize (2)
amir.color("blue")
amir.setheading(90)
amir.penup()
#bullet 1
jonafat = turtle.Turtle()
jonafat.shape("circle")
jonafat.shapesize(0.5)
jonafat.speed(2)
jonafat.pensize (1)
jonafat.color("black")
jonafat.penup()
jonafat.ht()

hossein = turtle.Turtle()
hossein.shape("arrow")
hossein.shapesize(1)
hossein.speed(10)
hossein.pensize (2)
hossein.color("gold")
hossein.setheading(90)
hossein.penup()
#bullet 
jonafat2 = turtle.Turtle()
jonafat2.shape("circle")
jonafat2.shapesize(0.5)
jonafat2.speed(2)
jonafat2.pensize (1)
jonafat2.color("black")
jonafat2.penup()
jonafat2.ht()
#scoreboard
TT = turtle.Turtle() 
TT.ht()
TT.penup()
TT.goto(-500,200)
TT.color("black")
TT.write("0", move = False, align = "center", font = ("Arial", 20, "normal"))
#second scoreboard
TT = turtle.Turtle() 
TT.ht()
TT.penup()
TT.goto(-500,200)
TT.color("black")
TT.write("0", move = False, align = "center", font = ("Arial", 20, "normal"))

x = 0
y = 0
amirs = 2
hosseins = 2
auto = 15 
vanguard = 15
trump = 0
time = 1
score = 0
panda = 295

def up():
    global amir
    global x
    global amirs
    global hosseins
    amir.seth(90)
    n = 1
    for i in range(0, n):
        amir.sety(amir.ycor()+10)
        n + 1

def down():
    global amir
    global x
    global amirs
    global hosseins
    amir.seth(270)
    n = 1
    for i in range(0, n):
        amir.sety(amir.ycor()-10)
        n + 1

def left():
    global amir
    global x
    global amirs
    global hosseins
    amir.seth(180)
    n = 1
    for i in range(0, n):
        amir.setx(amir.xcor()-10)
        n + 1

def right():
    global amir
    global x
    global amirs
    global hosseins
    amir.seth(0)
    n = 1
    for i in range(0, n):
        amir.setx(amir.xcor()+10)
        n + 1

def up2():
    global hossein
    global y
    global hosseins
    hossein.seth(90)
    n = 1
    for i in range(0, n):
        hossein.sety(hossein.ycor()+10)
        n + 1

def down2():
    global hossein
    global y
    global hosseins
    hossein.seth(270)
    n = 1
    for i in range(0, n):
        hossein.sety(hossein.ycor()-10)
        n + 1

def left2():
    global hossein
    global y
    global hosseins
    hossein.seth(180)
    n = 1
    for i in range(0, n):
        hossein.setx(hossein.xcor()-10)
        n + 1

def right2():
    global hossein
    global y
    global hosseins
    hossein.seth(0)
    n = 1
    for i in range(0, n):
        hossein.setx(hossein.xcor()+10)
        n + 1

def collisionCheck(jonafat, hossein):
    crash = True
    jonafat1X = jonafat.xcor()
    jonafat1Y = jonafat.ycor()
    hossein2X = hossein.xcor()
    hossein2Y = hossein.ycor()
    jonafatPos = (int(jonafat1X), int(jonafat1Y))
    hosseinPos = (int(hossein2X), int(hossein2Y))
    if jonafatPos != hosseinPos:
        crash = False
    if jonafatPos == hosseinPos:
        crash = True
    return crash

def clock():
    global time
    time = time-1

def move():
    global auto
    global vanguard
    global score
    global time
    wn.ontimer(clock,1000)
    angle = amir.heading()
    jonafat.ht()
    jonafat.speed(10)
    jonafat.setpos(amir.xcor(), amir.ycor())
    if angle == 0:
        trump = 1. 
        time = time-1
        jonafat.showturtle()
        jonafat.speed(2)
        n = 1
        for i in range(0, n):
            jonafat.goto(amir.xcor()+300, amir.ycor())
            n + 1
        infLoop = 1
        while infLoop == 1:
                if collisionCheck(jonafat, hossein) == True:
                    infLoop = 0
                    break
                    score = score + 1
                    TT.clear()
                    TT.write(score, move = False, align = "center", font = ("Arial", 20, "normal"))

                if time == 0:
                    break
                    infLoop = 0


    if angle == 90:
        jonafat.showturtle()
        jonafat.speed(2)
        n = 1
        for i in range(0, n):
            jonafat.goto(amir.xcor(),amir.ycor()+300)
            n + 1
    if angle == 180:
        jonafat.showturtle()
        jonafat.speed(2)
        n = 1
        for i in range(0, n):
            jonafat.goto(amir.xcor()-300, amir.ycor())
            n + 1
    if angle == 270:
        jonafat.showturtle()
        jonafat.speed(2)
        n = 1
        for i in range(0, n):
            jonafat.goto(amir.xcor(), amir.ycor()-300)
            n + 1


def move2():
    angle2 = hossein.heading()
    jonafat2.ht()
    jonafat2.speed(10)
    jonafat2.setpos(hossein.xcor(), hossein.ycor())
    if angle2 == 0:
        jonafat2.showturtle()
        jonafat2.speed(2)
        n = 1
        for i in range(0, n):
            jonafat2.goto(hossein.xcor()+300, hossein.ycor())
            n + 1
    if angle2 == 90:
        jonafat2.showturtle()
        jonafat2.speed(2)
        n = 1
        for i in range(0, n):
            jonafat2.goto(hossein.xcor(), hossein.ycor()+300)
            n + 1
    if angle2 == 180:
        jonafat2.showturtle()
        jonafat2.speed(2)
        n = 1
        for i in range(0, n):
            jonafat2.goto(hossein.xcor()-300, hossein.ycor())
            n + 1
    if angle2 == 270:
        jonafat2.showturtle()
        jonafat2.speed(2)
        n = 1
        for i in range(0, n):
            jonafat2.goto(hossein.xcor(), hossein.ycor()-300)
            n + 1








wn.onkeypress(up, "w")
wn.onkeypress(down, "s")
wn.onkeypress(left, "a")
wn.onkeypress(right, "d")
wn.onkeypress(up2, "Up")
wn.onkeypress(down2, "Down")
wn.onkeypress(left2, "Left")
wn.onkeypress(right2, "Right")
wn.onkeypress(move2, "Shift_R")

wn.onkeypress(move, "space")

wn.listen()
```

This is the part I have trouble with

```
def collisionCheck(jonafat, hossein):
    crash = True
    jonafat1X = jonafat.xcor()
    jonafat1Y = jonafat.ycor()
    hossein2X = hossein.xcor()
    hossein2Y = hossein.ycor()
    jonafatPos = (int(jonafat1X), int(jonafat1Y))
    hosseinPos = (int(hossein2X), int(hossein2Y))
    if jonafatPos != hosseinPos:
        crash = False
    if jonafatPos == hosseinPos:
        crash = True
    return crash

def clock():
    global time
    time = time-1

def move():
    global auto
    global vanguard
    global score
    global time
    wn.ontimer(clock,1000)
    angle = amir.heading()
    jonafat.ht()
    jonafat.speed(10)
    jonafat.setpos(amir.xcor(), amir.ycor())
    if angle == 0:
        trump = 1. 
        time = time-1
        jonafat.showturtle()
        jonafat.speed(2)
        n = 1
        for i in range(0, n):
            jonafat.goto(amir.xcor()+300, amir.ycor())
            n + 1
        infLoop = 1
        while infLoop == 1:
                if collisionCheck(jonafat, hossein) == True:
                    infLoop = 0
                    break
                    score = score + 1
                    TT.clear()
                    TT.write(score, move = False, align = "center", font = ("Arial", 20, "normal"))

                if time == 0:
                    break
                    infLoop = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears your only checking if their position is the same, although two objects can pass close to each other so that they visually collide, but aren't on the exact same position as each other.

You'll want to take their dimensions into account to properly check for collisions. The easiest way to check if they collide is to take the distance between their positions and check if it's smaller than a certain value. Although better options exist.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of all this:

```
def collisionCheck(jonafat, hossein):
    crash = True
    jonafat1X = jonafat.xcor()
    jonafat1Y = jonafat.ycor()
    hossein2X = hossein.xcor()
    hossein2Y = hossein.ycor()
    jonafatPos = (int(jonafat1X), int(jonafat1Y))
    hosseinPos = (int(hossein2X), int(hossein2Y))
    if jonafatPos != hosseinPos:
        crash = False
    if jonafatPos == hosseinPos:
        crash = True
    return crash
```

Let's take advantage of @JoshuaWaring's advice as well as turtle's `distance()` method and come up with something more like:

```
PERSONAL_SPACE = 10  # assign this to be how close is too close

def collisionCheck(jonafat, hossein):
    return jonafat.distance(hossein) < PERSONAL_SPACE
```

Let's rework the rest of the code to produce a minimally playable game:

```
# imports turtles
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

PERSONAL_SPACE = 15  # assign this to be how close is too close
FIRE_DISTANCE = 300
FONT = ('Arial', 36, 'normal')

# Sets screen, turtle program, and color group
screen = Screen()
screen.setup(1000, 800)
screen.bgcolor('springgreen')

def collisionCheck(bullet, player):
    return bullet.distance(player) < PERSONAL_SPACE

def up1():
    player1.seth(90)
    player1.forward(10)

def down1():
    player1.seth(270)
    player1.forward(10)

def left1():
    player1.seth(180)
    player1.forward(10)

def right1():
    player1.seth(0)
    player1.forward(10)

def clock1():
    global time1, score1

    if collisionCheck(bullet1, player2):
        score1 += 1
        TT1.undo()
        TT1.write(score1, align='center', font=FONT)
        time1 = 1
    else:
        bullet1.forward(1)

    time1 -= 1

    if time1:
        screen.ontimer(clock1, 10)
    else:
        bullet1.hideturtle()

def fire1():
    global time1

    bullet1.setpos(player1.pos())
    bullet1.setheading(player1.heading())
    bullet1.showturtle()

    time1 = FIRE_DISTANCE
    screen.ontimer(clock1, 100)

screen.onkeypress(up1, 'w')
screen.onkeypress(down1, 's')
screen.onkeypress(left1, 'a')
screen.onkeypress(right1, 'd')
screen.onkeypress(fire1, 'space')

def up2():
    player2.seth(90)
    player2.forward(10)

def down2():
    player2.seth(270)
    player2.forward(10)

def left2():
    player2.seth(180)
    player2.forward(10)

def right2():
    player2.seth(0)
    player2.forward(10)

def clock2():
    global time2, score2

    if collisionCheck(bullet2, player1):
        score2 += 1
        TT2.undo()
        TT2.write(score2, align='center', font=FONT)
        time2 = 1
    else:
        bullet2.forward(1)

    time2 -= 1

    if time2:
        screen.ontimer(clock2, 10)
    else:
        bullet2.hideturtle()

def fire2():
    global time2

    bullet2.setpos(player2.pos())
    bullet2.setheading(player2.heading())
    bullet2.showturtle()

    time2 = FIRE_DISTANCE
    screen.ontimer(clock2, 100)

screen.onkeypress(up2, 'Up')
screen.onkeypress(down2, 'Down')
screen.onkeypress(left2, 'Left')
screen.onkeypress(right2, 'Right')
screen.onkeypress(fire2, '0')

player1 = Turtle('arrow')
player1.speed('fastest')
player1.color('blue')
player1.setheading(180)
player1.penup()
player1.forward(10)

# bullet 1
bullet1 = Turtle('circle', visible=False)
bullet1.shapesize(0.5)
bullet1.speed('fastest')
bullet1.color('black', 'blue')
bullet1.penup()

player2 = Turtle('arrow')
player2.speed('fastest')
player2.color('gold')
player2.setheading(0)
player2.penup()
player2.forward(10)

# bullet 2
bullet2 = Turtle('circle', visible=False)
bullet2.shapesize(0.5)
bullet2.speed('fastest')
bullet2.color('black', 'gold')
bullet2.penup()

# scoreboard
TT1 = Turtle(visible=False)
TT1.penup()
TT1.goto(-450, 300)
TT1.color('blue')
TT1.write('0', align='center', font=FONT)

# second scoreboard
TT2 = Turtle(visible=False)
TT2.penup()
TT2.goto(450, 300)
TT2.color('gold')
TT2.write('0', align='center', font=FONT)

time1 = 0
score1 = 0

time2 = 0
score2 = 0

screen.listen()

screen.mainloop()
```

Still needs additional work, i.e. doesn't handle (or disable) multiple shots correctly, etc.

[image]